# android prevent dialog being displayed

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, ussd

I am writing an app which needs to send USSD messages to update my server and I am using the following to do so:

```
startActivityForResult( new Intent( Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse( "tel:" + ussd ) ), 0 );
```

Is there a means by which I can stop the progress dialog from being displayed and prevent the confirmation dialog as well so that I can send my updates in the background?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you get any way to it?